# How to make an input box auto size to whatever space is left on its current line

Tags: html, css

So basically I have a list with corresponding input fields and I would like the inputs to fill the line next to there heading automatically. I can do this by manually setting each input box's size, but I was hoping there was another way to do this as I have a lot of fields to do this to.

#### HTML

```
<div class="container1">
    <ul>
        <li>Name: <input type="text" name="name"></li>
        <li>Age: <input type="text" name="age"></li>
        <li>Gender: <input type="text" name="gender"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

#### CSS

```
.container1 {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

input {
    float: right;
    width: auto;
}
```

Hopefully this all makes sense. I have a 200x200 pixels box with some input fields next to a corresponding list item. Instead of having the input boxes all the same width I was hoping to be able to get them to auto size to the remaining space between the list item and the end of the box. Yes, I can manually do this to each of them, but I was hoping to not have to go down that path.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `flexbox`:

```css
li {
  display: flex;
}
li input {
  flex: 1;
}
```

```html
<ul>
  <li><span>Name:</span> <input type="text" name="name" /></li>
  <li><span>Age:</span>  <input type="text" name="age"  /></li>
</ul>
```

Answer (score -1):

This may be what you are expecting:

```css
.container1 {
    height: 200px;
    width: 200px;
}

input {
    float: right;
    width: auto;
}

ul li{display:flex}
```

```html
<div class="container1">
    <ul>
        <li>Name: <input type="text" name="name"></li>
        <li>Age: <input type="text" name="age"></li>
        <li>Gender: <input type="text" name="gender"></li>
    </ul>
</div>
```

Comment: no sorry, i was wanting them to all align on the right and fill back towards the left. Pete's example is what i was looking for but thankyou